# How do I get to a control in a subform

Tags: vba, ms-access, setfocus, subform

I want to go to a control in a subform in order to be able to enter data.
I can make a DoCmd.OpenForm but then I get an extra copy of the subform on top of the main form. I would rather go directly to the subform. I have tried a lot of options and the following I thought was the most promising

```
Me.Subform.SetFocus
Me.Subform.Form.mycotrol.SetFocus
DoCmd.GoToControl "mycontrol"
```

This piece of code does not stop at the Subform to let me enter data. I have also tried  Me!Subform with the same result. I have thought of adding a Stop statement, but then I don't know how to resume execution when data has been entered to the subform.
I think there is something I have not understood. Can someone help me out?
Biørn Veirø

Comment: In design mode, set the control's tab stop to true and the tab index to zero. Then do the same for the subform. Once the parent form is opened, the control should have the focus.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is single threaded. It can't work with Access forms this way. You could do it with a modal popup that returns a value, like an `InputBox`. Access forms don't return a value this way.

If you really want to have a step by step using Access forms then you need to hook in to form events. For this specific case I think the event you want is `TextBox.AfterUpdate`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.afterupdate-event

You can have different events on each control object, allowing you to have code that runs after each input.

Comment: to HackSlash: To me a modal popup would more or less be the same as getting another instance of my subform which I can get by DoCmd.Openform method.

Answer (score 0):

First set focus to the subform *control*, then the control in the form:

```vb
Me!YourSubformControlName.SetFocus
Me!YourSubformControlName.Form!YourControl.SetFocus
```